# php/curl - get extension of image on remote server using headers

Tags: php, image, curl

There is a form on my website that allows the upload of images from a remote server. When the user enters the link and submits, I want to check the file and make sure it's the right extension before I copy it off to my server.

I tried to directly use exif_imagetype, but allow_url_fopen is not allowed on the server so need help. I think using curl will solve the problem, but I'm not sure how to get the image extension from the header.

Thanks in advanced!

---

### solution

```
$ch = curl_init ($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_exec ($ch);

$content_type = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
echo $content_type;
```

Thanks to Mario!

Comment: Headers don't contain extensions. Do you mean the MIME type perhaps?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE) returns no charset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747504/php-curl-getinfoch-curlinfo-content-type-returns-no-charset)

Comment: image/jpeg - these types

Comment: Yes, that's the mime types. Use curl_getinfo() as in that other example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**solution**

```
$ch = curl_init ($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_exec ($ch);

$content_type = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
echo $content_type;
```

Thanks to Mario!

Answer (score 0):

Based on a few responses, I was trying to display an image from a curl request, and dynamically figure out the headers Content-Type. Using what Mario did, and some other things, here is a function which will correctly display an image from a standard url or file, and correctly put in the header. All PHP.

```
function displayImage( $filename ) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $options =  array(

        CURLOPT_URL => $filename,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPGET => true,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 60,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60

    );

    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    header('Content-Type: ' . curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE));

    if(!curl_errno($ch)){
        curl_close($ch);
        $img = imagecreatefromstring($response);
        imagejpeg($img);
        imagedestroy($img);
        return true;
    }
    else{
        curl_close($ch);
        return curl_error($ch);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way:

```
$src = 'https://example.com/image.jpg';
$size = getimagesize($src);
$extension = image_type_to_extension($size[2]);
```